# What would be the easiest way to create database of packaging of package in warehousing database?

Tags: database-design

I am creating a warehouse application for a client where goods are received in boxes.
The problem is, they contain more boxes in it.
Like if I have a product say Apples, then they receive 5 Boxes of Apples each containing 3 boxes in it. So in all there are 15 small boxes of apples.
Now, the question is how to simplify this task in my database?
Like I want bags in bags, box in bags, bags in box, etc etc.
This is critical because, again I have to code algorithm for remaining stock, current stock and returned stock too.

Comment: Something similar to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159340/110455)?

Comment: @McNets Yep, thats it! Thanks alot.